# Angular ngswitch delivers unexpected result

Tags: angular, typescript

this is my very first question at stackoverflow. Usually I get by pretty good by just reading other questions.

I am getting to know Angular at the moment, and I wonder why the ngSwitch directive is giving me results I wouldnt expect.

I created a component for my angular app that returns a ngx-bootstrap dropdown which I plan to use in different views. I dont know if this makes any architectural sense, but thats not the point here. If you have time, I certainly appreciate a comment to the architectural approach.

Now I hand over a `Map<string, string>` to my Dropdown component where key is what I want to show as an item in the Dropdown and value is the url I want to navigate to. This actually works nicely.

The ngx-bootstrap DropDown lets you put a divider in your Dropdown to seperate certain Dropdown items. To specify where a divider should appear, I thought I could simply hand over a key-value just like `['dropDownDivider', '']` and use ngSwitch to get the divider into my Dropdown HTML-Markup.

This actually works, the only thing is, the divider is always the last item in the Dropdown, no matter in which order I hand over the Map Collection.

This is what I hand over to my Dropdown component:

```
listitems = new Map([
  ['Alle', '#'],
  ['Detailseite', '#'],
  ['dropDownDivider', ''],
  ['Entfernen', '#'],
  ['Einstellungen', '#']
])
```

My @Input decorator `@Input() listItems: Map<string, string>;`

This is the list part of the Dropdown component view (I use angulars keyvalue pipe):

```
<!-- DropDown List -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let listItem of listItems | keyvalue">
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="listItem.key">
        <li *ngSwitchCase="'dropDownDivider'" class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li *ngSwitchDefault>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{listItem.value}}">{{listItem.key}}</a>
        </li>
     </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
```

I would expect that there is a divider in my dropdown list between 'Detailseite' and 'Entfernen'. The divider is always in the last Position, no matter in which position I put it in the Map collection.

Can someone explain this behaviour to me? If I log my Map to the console,  its values are still in the order I put them initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [KeyValue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) orders the entries by key.

If you want to pass an ordered list of items, don't use a Map and the KeyValue pipe. Just pass an array of items.

Comment: Thanks for your Input. I want to avoid defining a class. Could I use a generic Array? How would that look like?

If it orders it by Key, why would 'dropDownDivider' be in last place? What is it order by when not alphebatically?

Comment: It's ordered lexicographically. In lexicographic ordre (i.e. the numeric order of the Unicode characters), uppercase ASCII letters come before lowercase ASCII letters. Why would you need to define a class? You can pass an array of arrays (as you're doing now to construct your map), or better, an array of objects. These objects can implement an interface, to make your code type-safe and readable.

Comment: It works now perfectly fine, thanks for taking the time to help out a newbie. I use `@Input() listItems: [{name: string, url: string}];` with:
`listitems = [
      {name: 'Alle', url: '#'},
      {name: 'dropDownDivider', url: '#'},
      {name: 'Einstellungen', url: '#'}
    ];`